# Cannot add email channel to Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I have a bot that is, otherwise, working fine on the Bot Framework.  However, when I attempt to add an email channel (using my work Office 365 account), I'm recieving an error:

> "Oops, something went wrong: Empty service error response. ID:
>   bDrf6uBjcBU="

(obviously the ID changes each time).

I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Mailboxes must be accessible via username/password.  Here is a tool you can use to test Exchange Server connectivity: https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

Comment: Same problem here, though the connectivity tests went successfully. I tried these: Microsoft Exchange Web Services Connectivity Tests: Synchronization, Notification, Availability, and Automatic Replies
and Service Account Access (Developers). Internet Email Tests
Inbound SMTP Email
POP Email
IMAP Email